Which recognized mathematical journal accepts submissions in Chinese language
I know from experience that some [mathematical-journals] from France allow French submissions. And on the arXiv you can see now and then a math paper in French and not only in English.
I've checked the submission guidelines from "Science China Mathematics", "Peking Mathematical Journal" and "Acta Mathematica Sinica" (both the English Series and the Chinese Series) and they accept only submissions in English. Although, it is called "Chinese Series", this series also only accepts English submissions. I don't know other recognized Chinese math journals except these three.
Hence, the question: Which recognized mathematical journal accepts [chinese-language-submissions]? It must not be necessarily a journal published in China but most likely will be. The higher the impact factor and the more top-notch, the more I would be interested in it.

I downloaded some recent papers from the Chinese Series of Acta Mathematica Sinica and they were written in Chinese.

@theL Really! I was not able to download them and the titles were all English. Then, this would be the solution I go for.

@theL Indeed, the titles and abstracts are in English but the main body is Chinese. I've downloaded some as well. That's all I need.

If you are interested in open access journals specifically, DOAJ has great tools for searching for those that accept articles for a given language:
This link lists those for mathematics journals with Chinese language submissions specifically.
[DOAJ] also lists metadata for impact factor ratings, and is searchable by topical coverage, fees, peer review type, open access policies, etc.

Thank you @Eric This is interesting but in the list there's no journal specifically for mathematics like the three examples in my question.

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any reputable math research journal, with an international reputation, which accepts papers in Chinese. Moreover, I don't recall having ever seen (in English-language research papers) a citation of any Chinese-language research paper published within the past forty years. There might be some somewhere, but they are surely very rare.
The one famous Chinese-language paper I'm aware of was Jingrun Chen's 1966 paper on the "almost twin prime conjecture", published during the Cultural Revolution, and Chen published an English-language version with more details in 1973.
Nowadays, Chinese mathematicians who want their work to get widely noticed write in English. It is not exactly fair that I can write in my native language and get noticed, and Chinese mathematicians can't, but that is the reality.

Yes, indeed, as unfair as the situation is, this is the current state of affairs: don't publish a math paper in Mandarin if you want people in Europe and North-and-South America to know what you've done. There is a similar issue with some Japanese work which is deliberately (and understandably) in Japanese... But/and one might choose not to be the rebel who fights for change... depending on one's security.

Acta Mathematica Sinica, Chinese Series is a top-notch journal which publishes Chinese papers. It might be enough for some to get noticed within China.
